# Upload beside images file on cloudinary

Tags: api, cloudinary

Can I upload others than image file on [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)? If i can, is it use the same API to upload it? Or i have to use different API to upload it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary provides end-to-end solution (i.e. upload, storage, maintenance, manipulations & CDN based delivery) for your [Images](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images) & [videos](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_videos).
It also allows you to upload, manage & deliver any other file types as further explained here: http://cloudinary.com/blog/using_cloudinary_to_manage_all_your_website_s_assets_in_the_cloud

More general information on uploading your assets to Cloudinary can be gained from the following docs: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload

> Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("sample_spreadsheet.xls", 
>                                    :public_id => "sample_spreadsheet", 
>                                    **:resource_type => :raw**)